# Why does the same material look different on another object?

Tags: materials

I have a PBR material. I have assigned it to the floor and the side wall. On the floor it has good scale, but on the side wall it looks compressed. The side wall and the floor has the same material. How can I get the same correct scale on both objects?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedural Brick texture in the 'WO_Wood Texture' node group has no vector input connected to it so it uses 'Generated' texture space that maps the texture's x y z values to the bounding box of the object so it depends on the size and orientation of the object - if you rotated the object and applied rotation (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) you would see the texture change its orientation. To solve the issue you need to use texture space that is uniform in size. You could use 'Object' space and it would be the same size for objects with the same scale, but you would need to match orientation by applying it while the object rotation is aligned to the texture and then rotating it back to the way it needs to be in the scene. My recommendation however would be to use UV texture space and match the sizes and orientation of your UV maps:

[image]

Comment: It solved but pbr material are working without uv as i know is that correct or wrong i dont know. Thanks

Comment: This material can just be called 'a material' without the buzzword PBR. Pretty much all materials can be called PBR, because they are all based on physics more or less in one way or another. PBR might also refer to a specific workflow where texture maps are created keeping scene referred values in mind. The term is pretty much useless and changes nothing. It certainly has nothing to do with what way of mapping a texture you choose. You can use 'Object' texture space as I explained to get same results. I just think UV is easier to understand as it is the most common way to map textures in 3d.